# MySQL exact URL search

Tags: php, mysql, url

So I'm trying to merge two databases of company information (Table A and Table B from here on out) where the most common (and reliable) single reference point is the website URL. Table A is up-to-date, and Table B is to be updated.

I've extracted the URLs from Table A and cleaned them up using PHP (about 6000 URLs) and the plan is to find and update some information in Table B based on the URLs found (but not the URL itself).

In Table A the URLs are all either `domain.com` or `www.domain.com` or `www.subdomain.domain.com` without http:// or any trailing /'s or other URL data. In Table B they are raw URLs which might contain any extra information with them such as http:// etc.

Now I've tried searching for the company by the URL in Table B like so:

```
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE website LIKE '%$url1%' OR website LIKE '%$url2%'...
```

While this works, it is also pulling out information that isn't correct. For example, I don't have `bt.com` (or any variation of) in the list from Table A, yet it is matching on it in Table B (there is a `www.corporate.bt.com` in Table A which I think it is matching on).

So, how can I stop this from happening? It's clearly finding something LIKE it in the URL list, but I only want to match on the exact string. So in the example above, if I'm searching for `www.corporate.bt.com` it should only return that if it finds it within a string (`http://www.corporate.bt.com/` is fine, `http://bt.com/` is not)

Also, what would be the best possible way of performing this action with a dataset this large? Table A has around 6,000 URLs, Table B has 14,000 (not all of Table A will be in Table B).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE won't return exact search but you can use MySql `REGEXP` for exact search, it will find exact result in search filed and return only exact url

```
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE website REGEXP '[[:<:]]$url1[[:>:]]' OR 
                              website REGEXP '[[:<:]]$url2[[:>:]]'
```

Or if filed have only single url then you can use `=` operator

```
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE website = '$url1' OR website = '$url2'
```

**UPDATE**
In this you can expend REGEX serarch and input only `SERVER_NAME` e.g `domain.com`, `domain1.com`, `abc.domain.com`, see below query

```
$url = "doamin.com";
$url1 = "domain1.com";
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE 
    website REGEXP '^(htt(p|ps):\/\/|htt(p|ps):\/\/www\.)($url)$' OR 
    website REGEXP '^(htt(p|ps):\/\/|htt(p|ps):\/\/www\.)($url1)$'
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work as intended. The first one pulls the same results as LIKE. The second one doesn't wont work as if I'm searching for `www.bt.com` it wont match on `http://www.bt.com/`

Comment: @daogle see updated section, it would be helpful you

Comment: With my answer I posted, your first suggestion worked great (though it did take 6 minutes to run the query). I did try your last example, but after 15 minutes I stopped the query - performance was too bad! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I hadn't filtered through the list of address' in Table A well enough, and it appears that a url of 'http' had slipped through - which meant that every url that contained 'http' was being found...

So I added another filter which checked for the presence of a . in the URL, which ensured that it was at least `something.something`

```
if (strpos($domain, ".") !== false) {
    // It has a .±
}
```

Comment: Use if(strpos($domain, '.') >= 0) for checking existence, because strpos will return -1 (not false) if nothing is found.

Comment: @Yami While I think that would work, [According to the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) `strpos` appears to return false (or rather, should be checked in the same way I am checking)